# JQuery AJax Result Echo PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I must to check the result of Ajax are same with some PHP variable value.
Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you in advance for help.

My Ajax HTML:

```
<?php
$x = '<p id="ip"></p>';
$y = '2_2_1_3';

if($x == $y){
  echo $x;
}
?>

<a id="input" href="#">Get value<input type="hidden" value="2_2_1_3"></a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#input").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "ip2.php", 
      data:'ip=' + $(this).parent().find('input').val(),
      success: function(data){
      $("#ip").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php
if($_POST['ip'] >= 0){
  $ip = $_POST['ip'];  
  echo $ip;  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = '<p id="ip"></p>';
$y = '2_2_1_3';
if($x == $y){ // this will never be true because $x is diferent of $y
echo $x;  //so you will never print this out
}
```

And you won't have the element with id="ip" to print the result from your ajax

```
success: function(data){
  $("#ip").html(data);
  }
```

For it to work try this:

```
<?php
$x = '<p id="ip"></p>';
$y = '2_2_1_3';
echo $x;
?>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thank you.
Badly, how to make the $x is same value with the $y.
I trying for strip_tags (PHP) but still not getting same.

Comment: You mean doing this : $x = '<p id="ip">2_2_1_3</p>';
$y = '2_2_1_3';
if(strip_tags($x) == $y){echo $x;}; ?

Comment: So much helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but you can always send your post data as an object in javascript, for simplicity you can use the post function.

Example:

```
    $.post( "ip2.php", { ip: $(this).parent().find('input').val() }, function( data ) {
      console.log( data );
    });
```

More info:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Is there possible if not using Ajax for getting result back to main file.

Comment: Ajax is just a concept that jQuery invented, XHR is a very agile method to communicate with PHP from JS, the alternative is through post data, normal form and input elements through HTML, what specifically did you have in mind?

Comment: Now I knew. Thank you and now I using your code for simplicity my Ajax code. Thank you.